# How to restart onCreateInputView()?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-softkeyboard, android-inflate

I have a keyboard with a onCreateInputView() method, I have to edit the keyboard dinamically and I have to restard the onCreateInputView() when particular preferences changes

Comment: and what did you do, and your problem with that is...?

Comment: I have a value on sharedpreferences and if is true, I need to inflate layout1, if is false layout2. If I am on layout1 to change into layout2 I have to stop layout1, and call onCreateInputView(): how can I stop and recall that?

Comment: did you read this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html#onCreateInputView() ?

Comment: no... I have to set  setInputView(View), right?

Answer (score 9):

Add this line in onStartInputView method.

```
setInputView(onCreateInputView());
```

Answer (score 1):

From https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html#onCreateInputView():

> Create and return the view hierarchy used for the input area (such as
>   a soft keyboard). This will be called once, when the input area is
>   first displayed. You can return null to have no input area; the
>   default implementation returns null.
>
> To control when the input view is displayed, implement
>   onEvaluateInputViewShown(). To change the input view after the first
>   one is created by this function, use setInputView(View).